# Javascript: unshift key value array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a specific item on the front of an array but I can't work out how to do this? I know you do it with unshift, but I'm not sure how to do it with a key value array?

```
var outgoingHeaders = {
    "send_client_version": 1,
    "send_auth_ticket": 5
};

function sendPacket(packetName, packetData) {
    const packetId = outgoingHeaders[packetName];
    const packetArray = {'packet_id' : packetId };
    // TODO: Add packetArray at the start of packetData
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(packetData));
}
```

Example of calling it...

```
sendPacket('send_auth_ticket', {
    'auth_ticket' : authTicket,
});
```

Comment: Is `packetData` really an array? From what you wrote it seems like it's an object, and in that case you can't really control the order of the items.

Comment: Not sure if this is the source of confusion but just in case: unlike some programming languages there is no "key value array" (or what some call an associative array) in Javascript.

Comment: Not sure why you think its an object?

Comment: Not sure why *you* think it's an array…

Comment: Because I pass an array to the function..

Comment: No you don't. `{}` is an *object*, `[]` is an array.

Comment: So I'm guess I'm asking how to do it with a key value object, I'm sorry if it was called something else but I usually call it a key value array, I apologize.

Comment: Then "unshifting" and "order" are inappropriate too, since objects don't have an order. Do you merely want to add the key-value pair into the object…?

Comment: I just want to ensure that packet_id is the first item in the json string when sent to the server.

Comment: And that ain't gonna happen. Objects. Have. No. Guaranteed. Order. Neither in Javascript nor JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` array method, like:

```
function sendPacket(packetName, packetData) {
  const packetId = outgoingHeaders[packetName];
  const packetArray = [{'packet_id' : packetId }];
  const data = packetArray.concat(packetData);
  socket.send(JSON.stringify(packetData));
}
```

Nice thing about this, you keep the immutability of your variables :)

Comment: Apparently concat doesn't exist?

Comment: packets.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: packetArray.concat is not a function

Comment: packetArray need to be a array. I edited there :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provided any JSON sample this is a suggestion:

```js
var outgoingHeaders = {
  "nameee" : 33
}


function sendPacket(packetName, packetData) {
    var packetId = outgoingHeaders[packetName];
    var packetArray = {'packet_id' : packetId };
    // TODO: Add packetArray on the front of packetData
    packetData.unshift(packetArray);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(packetData, null, 4));
}




sendPacket("nameee", [{'packet_id' : 14 }, {'packet_id' : 5 }])
```

Comment: I've updated my question to make it more clear.